# Use gcloud self encrypted disk with Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I need to encrypt the data on a block device and allow the Pod to access it as a volume.

I noticed its now possible on Google cloud to encrypt a new disk using [Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption)

Can I use self encrypted disk with Kubernetes and attach it to the Pod as volume?

If not, is there any other way to encrypt block device (for example LUKS) and use it with Pods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the the Google docs (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption) are that no key is required to mount the disk.  The keys are only provided at disk creation time.

So, the following should work without changes to kubernetes:

1. create encrypted disk "myencrypteddisk" per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption
2. create a pod which mounts GCEPD called "myencrypteddisk".
3. kubelet will mount the disk on the VM.  It's compute scope should be enough to perform the mount, IIUC.

Comment: got an error message saying: Failed to attach volume "myencrypteddisk" on node "MYNODE" with: googleapi: Error 400: projects/MYPROJECT/zones/europe-west1-c/disks/myencrypteddisk is protected with a customer supplied encryption key, but none was provided. ?!

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently integration with this feature, but we should add it, I filed:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13493

Currently you would have to encrypt each file individually, and use the [kubernetes secrets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/secrets) to distribute the keys to decrypt those files.